# Reading Image data by loop though

Tags: javascript, html

I want to read image data by the loop. But it is not working How can I resolve this error?

```js
var i = '';
var file = '';
var reader = '';
var tbase = [];
for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  var filename = $("#img" + i).val();
  if (filename != '') {
    file = document.getElementById('img' + i).files[0];
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      alert(reader.result);
      tbase[i] = reader.result;
      alert(tbase[i]);
      //localStorage.setItem("foundimage"+i, tbase);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
  window.onerror = function(msg, url, linenumber) {
    alert('Error message: ' + msg + '\nURL: ' + url + '\nLine Number: ' + linenumber);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="img4" id="img1">
<input type="file" name="img4" id="img2">
<input type="file" name="img3" id="img3">
<input type="file" name="img4" id="img4">
```

Comment: You need to call your script at some time AFTER the user adds a file. I created a snippet. Now add what you want to trigger the script. Also be consistent: `var file = $("#img" + i), fileName = file.val(), file = file[0].files[0]`

Comment: I am running code when someone submitting form

Comment: @mplungjan can you please write answer

Comment: You need a closure more than anything.